# How to synchronise update of an attribute that belongs to a module and a class

Tags: vb.net, oop

I'm new to vb.net, so forgive me if the question sounds awfully elementary to many of you. It is about maintaining objects contained in different classes/modules.  Currently I have a class called aggregated_SI. Below is the definition for aggregated_SI

```
Public Class Aggregated_SI
  Private _identifier As Integer
  Private _From_Firm As String
  Private _From_Account_Number As String
  Private _To_Account_Number As String
  Private _To_Firm As String
  Private _Security_Code As String
  Private _Quantity As Integer
  Private _Settlement_Amount As Decimal
  Private _Settlement_Ccy As String
End class
```

In my module, I have defined an attribute:

```
Private settlement_Instructions as List(Of Aggregated_SI)
```

As you can see, Aggregated_SI has various attributes, among them are from_account_number and to_account_number which actually refers to a name of another class account. The Account class has the following attributes:

```
Public Class Account
  Private _account_Number As String
  Private _security_Holding As Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
  Private _deliver_SIs As Dictionary(Of Integer, Aggregated_SI)
  Private _receiving_SIs As Dictionary(Of Integer, Aggregated_SI)
End class
```

the _deliver_SIs and _receiving_SIs are dictionary that contains the _identifier attribute from Aggregated_SI class as its key and aggregated_SI object as its value. Now, each account contains various aggregated_SIs object which are the subset of the attribute settlement_Instructions

The problem is, as I modify the Aggregated_SI objects inside the settlement_Instructions list, how do I ensure that the various aggregated_SI objects which are contained in _deliver_SIs and _receiving_SIs to be simultaneously updated at the same time? I've tried updating the corresponding SIs in _deliver_SIs and _receiving_SIs separately as I update the aggregated_SI inside settlement_Instructions but this feels redundant and it makes the code not easily read. Any suggestion as to how to approach this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Can't be of any help, but I think the way you are dealing with it now is how it needs to be because Aggregated_SI aren't the same objects (ie, you're using different instances of the class). If I understand your classes, you seem to have an ugly recursive relationship - Aggregated_SI contains Accounts which contains Aggregated_SI. Good luck!

Comment: The way I approach it currently is that I will create a dictionary of account object with its account number in string as the key. The account number in the class Aggregated_SI have from_account_number and to_account_number strings that I can use to select the appropriate account object from the list of accounts. But right now I'm still hard-coding the update for the accounts in the list and the list of aggregated_SIs